# ordered topological groups

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, ordered-groups

Is there a  partially order relation on $S^1$ whose corresponding order topology coincides to the standard topology of circle?Is there a totally order relation with such property?

what is a theory devoted to such questions  for compact topological groups?

Comment: What is the topology you consider standard on $X$ when we have a partial (non-linear) order? There is an up-topology, down-topology, interval topology, Scott topology and probably more. For linear orders there is one clear choice.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  i consider interval topology

Comment: OK, then the cutpoint argument won't work. That plus the fact that $\dim(X) \le 1$ for any LOTS can be used to show a lot of non-orderability results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's such a poset (not a totally ordered one, as already observed).

Here, if $X$ is a poset I understand that the interval topology is the topology defined by a prebasis consisting of those $U_{x_0}=\{x:x>x_0\}$ and $V_{y_0}=\{y:y<y_0\}$ where $x_0,y_0$ ranges over $X$.

Now define a set as follows: $$X=\{-\infty\}\sqcup(\mathbf{R}\times\{-1,1\})\sqcup\{+\infty\}$$

It has a natural topology making it homeomorphic to the circle ($(x_i,n_i)$ tends to $\pm\infty$ meaning that $x_i\to\pm\infty$ in the usual sense).

Now make it a poset as follow: $-\infty\le z\le +\infty$ for all $z$; on each of the two copies of $\mathbf{R}$, we take the usual ordering. Finally, for $e\in\{1,-1\}$, we say ($\sharp$) that $(x,e)\le (y,-e)$ if $x\le y-1$.

Then we see that the interval topology coincides with the previous one. At $\pm\infty$, this is clear: for each finite set $F$ with $-\infty\notin F$, there exists a neighborhood of $-\infty$ that is $\le y$ for each $y\in F$. At $(x,e)$, observe that for $t<1$, $\{z: (x-t,e)\le z\le (x+t,e)\}$ is reduced to $\{(y,e):x-t\le y\le x+t\}$. (Note that this uses the $-1$ in ($\sharp$)).

Comment: PS the question seems unrelated to any group structure on the circle...

Comment: The interval topology has a base consisting of all $(x_0, y_0)$, with $x_0 , y_0 \in X$, to which we have to add $X$,  not the subbase you mention. It matters because $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ are dense points and the interval topology is not Hausdorff.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma but is not a finite onterval, an intersection of two infinite interval?

Comment: @AliTaghavi no, $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ are not in any open intervals.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma possibly the standard definition of "interval topology" excludes intervals with a single bound, but this is hard to guess to people outside the area, since in the real line it is universally accepted that intervals can be unbounded. Actually I searched for the definition of "interval topology" in a poset without finding any, so I specified the one I'm using; the main question was whether the OP is happy with this definition.

Answer (score 2):

Not a total order: if $(X,<)$ is a connected LOTS (linearly ordered topological space) any $x$ in it that is not $\min(X)$ or $\max(X)$ is a cutpoint, meaning that $X\setminus\{x\}$ is disconnected.

But $S^1$ has no cutpoints at all.

Comment: Just note that $X\setminus \{x\} = \{y: y < x\} \cup \{y: y > x\}$ in a *linear* order and both sets are open by the definition of the order topology. The condition on $x$ is to ensure both parts are non-empty too, showing disconnectedness.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I realized that your argument does not work for POSET, according to your comment. But  what about the POSET case on circle?

Comment: @AliTaghavi I don't know yet. I don't think so, but I'd have to study the interval topology. I know quite a lot about LOTS from my studies, but posets aren't studied that much, only the Scott topology is popular. What sources do you recommend for that? And must the poset be consistent with the group as well? That would be even harder to realise.

Comment: I was not aware of Scott topology.your answer helped me to learn about it.So i appreciate your help. To be honest i  am familiar with POSET in the minimal manner(what I learned in undergraduate 30 years ago, the book of  Enderton, I think.)BTW today I was reviewing my recollection of those years so this lead me to the following extension of the Famous theorem that every set can be well ordered. let X be  a  set and  f is  a  map on X. Is there a  well order relation on X for which f is  increasing?

Comment: we read these materials from Enderton and  Lin & Lin,  I think. But I do not know any other references.